# Why changing global does not give error?

Tags: python, list, global, side-effects

Why on earth Python lets change not global declared list in function?

RE-UPDATED

```
numbers = []
num = 4

def add(n, thisnum=None):
    # changing global list without global declaration!
    numbers.append(n)
    if thisnum:
         num = thisnum
         print 'num assigned', thisnum
    ##numbers = ('one', 'two', 'three')
    ## adding this line makes error:
"""Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\test\glob_vals.py", line 13, in <module>
    add(i)
  File "J:\test\glob_vals.py", line 6, in add
    numbers.append(n)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'numbers' referenced before assignment
"""

for i in (1,2,3,564,234,23):
    add(i)

print numbers
add(10, thisnum= 19)
# no error
print num
# let the fun begin
num = [4]
add(10, num)
print num

# prints:
"""[1, 2, 3, 56, 234, 23]
num assigned 19
4
num assigned [4]
[4]

"""
```

If I put assignement to variable with same name then the action **before that line** becomes error, not the added line (byte code compiler spots it, I guess).

Comment: You seem to be confused about scoping rules. There are some questions on this with quality answers spread across SO, and docs.python.org also covers this.

Comment: I still think this is not trivial thing or obvious from documentation which I have studied much, being teacher and studied Computer Science since 1984.

Comment: I for one think it's simple - perhaps more complex than scoping rules in most languages, but still only a handful of rules without nasty exceptions.

Comment: Feels at least lot less painfull than Ada, from which we learned, what STRONG typing means (luckily that mainframe time the Ada compiler was not available to torture us, so that was only in theory).

Comment: Wait, wat? Every language has its rules, and Ada sure has a whole lot more in about every other area. You can't expect things to run smoothly when you don't know the rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't assigning to the global variable, you are calling a method on it which changes its contents. This is allowed.

What you can't do without the `global` keyword is this:

```
def add(n):
    #global numbers
    numbers = numbers + [n]
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\stackoverflow\python\test.py", line 8, in 
    add(i)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\stackoverflow\python\test.py", line 5, in add
    numbers = numbers + [n]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'numbers' referenced before assignment
```

The difference is that here I am not mutating the existing list - I'm trying to create a new list and reassign back to the global scope. But this cannot be done without the `global` keyword.

---

Regarding your update:

The following line is OK because it creates a new local name `num` in the scope of the function. This does not affect the value of the variable at the global scope.

```
num = thisnum
```

Answer (score 1):

`global x` **only** affests `x = ...` (namely, it makes this re-assign the global `x` instead of creating an independent local `x`). It doesn't affect `x.member = ...` (because that's a method call) or `x.mutating_method(...)`, because Python (*this* is not an issue of static vs. dynamic, btw) can't know (and doesn't care) that these method modify `self` in some way - so you'd have to prevent method calls on (objects pointed to by) global variables ... which is, of course, pointless.

Regarding update:
When you do `num = thisnum`, you are doing something completely different from `numbers.append(n)` - you are creating a local variable (because you didn't declare `global num`) and assigning it some value. This never even touches the global `num`.

Comment: @Tony: See my first sentence - Python assumes that `x` is local if it is assigned somewhere in the function, and as the error message tells you, the local `numbers` (it's a local because it *is* assigned later in the function and not declared `global`) has no value assigned to it at that point.

Comment: I do understand, but it makes nice 'back to the future' effect causing the line which was OK before to fail, because of later line. It just stresses the existence of byte compilation step. And passing in list as variable instead of writing same value as direct argument gives side effect back to caller.

Comment: @Tony: If you want immutability enforced, use Haskell ;) What would you propose instead?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are just *appending* to a list.

Accessing and assigning are different concepts. When you append a list, you are just calling a method which changes its value. Supposing you did `+=`, that would be assigning.

If you were to do this:

```
>>> numbers = []
>>> def add(n):
      numbers += n

>>> n = [1, 2]
>>> add(n)
```

It would fail because this is assignment.

To fix this, in the `add()` function, you add:

```
>>> def add(n):
        global numbers
        numbers += n
```